# Run Azure DevOps extension in the background

Tags: azure-devops, background-service, azure-devops-extensions

Is it possible to run Azure DevOps Web extension when you open any azure devops page?

Probably, there is exists something like `"type": "ms.vss-web.azure-load-action"` that starts when you open Azure DevOps Website.

In common way, extension contribution runs in a certain scenarios, like - opening hub, opening context menu, etc. Can you run an extension contribution in global context - after azure devops website was opened?

PS. I'he already searched in the [VSTS samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/contributions-guide/vss-extension.json), [extension points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/docs/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#dashboards) and azure [devops extension samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample)

Thank you, have a nice day!

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Yes, ty. I use "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-notifications" target now, because when its loaded it works in the background on all pages inside the project. The problem is that its loaded only when you open any work item form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, extensions don't support "load action". We use extensions to enhance Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server (TFS) with new web experiences, dashboard widgets, build tasks, and more. You may submit a user voice at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21